How to make garcon-url-handler open url in an INCOGNITO window?
$ garcon-url-handler https://example.com/

opens the URL in a regular browser window.
How to make it open it in an incognito window? No I don't want to type CTRL+SHIFT+N and paste it in the URL bar.
